# Stopping Jetty from throwing stacktrace whenever it receives an invalid HTTP request

Tags: java, url-rewriting, jetty, stack-trace, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am running my servlet application within Jetty, and it sometimes outputs the below-shown stack trace. I think this means it is receiving an invalid URL request, but I can't actually see the request. Can I handle this exception somwehere so that my logs are not clogged up with this nasty stack trace? And if so can it handled in my code, or does this error occur before getting to my code and therefore needs to be handled with Jetty configuration?

**EDIT**
So if I did move to Jeety 9 how could I configure it so the stacktrace goes and could I configure a suitable http response code

Alternaively, I've realized that jetty is receiving the request after it has been processed by http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/, is there something sensible I should configure in UrlRewriteFilter to do something else if the generated url is invalid.

```
2013-01-11 23:48:10.939:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte B0 in state 0
2013-01-11 23:48:10.939:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/ws/2/release/
org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte B0 in state 0
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable.appendByte(Utf8Appendable.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable.append(Utf8Appendable.java:99)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeString(UrlEncoded.java:709)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeTo(UrlEncoded.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeTo(UrlEncoded.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.mergeQueryString(Request.java:2045)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:103)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**EDIT**
It has been suggested that maybe this could be handled in my tuckey configuration so thsi is what it currently looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.1//EN"
        "http://tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.1.dtd">

<!--

    Configuration file for UrlRewriteFilter
    http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

-->
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
    <rule>
       <note>
           Matches urls like http://localhost:8080/ws/1/artist/?query=blur&amp;fmt=xml
           and converts to http://localhost:8080/?type=artist&amp;query=blur&amp;fmt=xml&amp;version=1
       </note>
       <from>^/ws/(\d)/(.*)/\?(.*)$</from>
       <to>/?version=$1&amp;type=$2&amp;$3</to>
     </rule>

    <rule>
        <note>
            The rule means that requests to /test/status/ will be redirected to /rewrite-status
            the url will be rewritten.
        </note>
        <from>/test/status/</from>
        <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/rewrite-status</to>
    </rule>


    <outbound-rule>
        <note>
            The outbound-rule specifies that when response.encodeURL is called (if you are using JSTL c:url)
            the url /rewrite-status will be rewritten to /test/status/.

            The above rule and this outbound-rule means that end users should never see the
            url /rewrite-status only /test/status/ both in their location bar and in hyperlinks
            in your pages.
        </note>
        <from>/rewrite-status</from>
        <to>/test/status/</to>
    </outbound-rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Comment: Which version of jetty?

Comment: jetty 8 but i could possibly change this

Comment: Which precise version of Jetty?  The complete version string.

Comment: I dont know ,i dont have direct access to the server, what difference does it make

Comment: Just saying Jetty 8 is insufficient to know what level of control you have over the logging, as it evolved over the years.  There might be a way to setup slf4j logging to filter that exception.  (Note: the ability to turn off stacktraces for specific named logs has been added to Jetty 9)

Comment: Ive found out it is jetty-hightide-8.1.7.v20120910

Comment: @PaulTaylor - I am asking a dumb question - what does the access.log say when this stack trace is thrown ?

Comment: user1428716 sory I dont know, i dot have access to the machine

Comment: The error is actually in the client, which tries to send a request uri not correctly utf-8 encoded. Can you post your tuckey configuration? The idea is to set up a rule which url-encodes utf-8 characters in tuckey

Comment: @guido good point, just added it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Write a log4j filter for this exception.