# Jenkins Active-Directory plugin trying to login automatically with non-existing user@my-domain

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, jenkins-plugins

I configured my jenkins using the active-directory via groovy. So far everything works fine. Only this one issue remains, that jenkins is trying to login against AD with some kind of default user automatically and regularly (more or less every other minute). This user of course does not exist so my logfile is full of exceptions. I don't know how do avoid these login attempts.

I always and constantly get this exception

```
Aug 09, 2019 1:41:48 PM hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider retrieveUser
WARNING: Credential exception trying to authenticate against <MY_DOMAIN> domain
org.acegisecurity.BadCredentialsException: Either no such user 'user@<MY_SERVER>' or incorrect password
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:614)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider$1.call(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:370)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider$1.call(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:340)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4767)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4764)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:340)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:303)
        at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:225)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:122)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:200)
        at org.acegisecurity.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:47)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderRealPasswordAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicHeaderRealPasswordAuthenticator.java:56)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:79)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Plugin Installation via ansible

```
# Jenkins master: install plugins
- name: Install Plugins on behalf of jenkins user {{jenkins_admin_user}}
  jenkins_plugin:
    name: "{{ item.key }}"
    url: http://<SERVERNAME>:8080
    url_username: "{{jenkins_admin_user}}"
    url_password: "{{jenkins_admin_pass}}"
  environment:
    http_proxy: http://<PROXY_USER>:<PROXY_PASS>@<PROXY_SERVER>:80
    https_proxy: http://<PROXY_USER>:<PROXY_PASS>@<PROXY_SERVER>:80
  register: plugin_result
  until: plugin_result is success
  retries: 10
  delay: 2
  with_items: # no version = latest
    - { key: "some-plugin"}
    - { key: "active-directory"}
    - { key: "some-other-plugin"}
```

my groovy script to setup the AD connection

```
#!groovy
import java.util.logging.Level
import java.util.logging.Logger
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.plugins.active_directory.*

/*
 * Setup active directory connection.
 * No information other than domain name necessary.
 */
def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
def log = Logger.getLogger(Jenkins.class.getName())

log.log(Level.INFO, "START - Create active directory realm")

final String domain = "<MY_DOMAIN>"
final String domainController = ""
final String site = ""
final String bindName = ""
final String bindPassword = ""
realm = new ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm(domain, site, bindName, bindPassword, domainController)
instance.setSecurityRealm(realm)
instance.save()

log.log(Level.INFO, "FINISHED - Create active directory realm")
```

The actual values for `<MY_DOMAIN>` and `<MY_SERVER>` etc. are correct.

Anyone ogot an idea how I can get rid of theses unwanted login attempts? Thanks guys and best regards. Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java developer, but based on [other](https://issues.rudder.io/issues/12023) [Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756100/stopping-jetty-from-throwing-stacktrace-whenever-it-receives-an-invalid-http-req) [stack traces](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2634) I've found online, that looks like it's just responding to an HTTP request.

Are you sure it's not just an HTTP request using bad credentials?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not just an invalid http request. I set up a fresh jenkins installation and installed a bunch of plugins using ansible. For every new step I removed the complete installation and installed again, so there is no old junk left (and hence causing this behavior). The jenkins installation without the active-directory plugin does not show any warnings or exceptions. After I installed and configured the AD plugin, this behavior starts immediately and without any further manual action. The plugin config is pretty simple and looks like I did it manually (basically just domain name)